# CRM 2011 Product Import "Duplicate Reference Found"

Tags: duplicates, crm, product

I've been trying to import some new products to our CRM Organization, although I always seem to get this error for the U of M column.

**"A Duplicate Lookup Reference was Found"**

[Error Log](http://s792.photobucket.com/user/anthony_banks2/media/uploadError_zpsd821bef6.png.html)

[My CSV File being Used](http://s792.photobucket.com/user/anthony_banks2/media/excelError_zps170814ea.png.html)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://exploringxrm.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/resolving-duplicate-lookup-references-in-import-process/). I think you need to explicitly map the u of m column.

Comment: Just to clarify, the data "each", whatever record type/column it is mapped does not uniquely identify a related record is what the error is saying